# How to run Debconf for a installed package via apt-get?

Tags: debian, configuration, apt

Installing some packages requires answering Debconf questions. Usually Debconf is called during installation (`after apt-get install [packages]`), thus new packages will use defined configurations.

My question is: how to reconfigure these packages again?
I already tried to `apt-get remove [packages]` and install that again but Debconf step is omitted and previous settings are used.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `dpkg-reconfigure packagename`?